# Not able to use babel "preset-env" plugin with NextJS

Tags: plugins, babeljs, next.js

I have a requirement where I am trying to use the Babel plugin "preset-env". This plugin compiles my NextJS project from ES6 to ES5. I have created the `.babelrlc` file as suggested by NextJS documentation and added my plugin like this:

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"],
    "plugins": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

When I try to run my project locally I get this error:

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/client/router.js
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-preset-env' from '/Users/agastya/Local/testcap/Sample-proj'
- If you want to resolve "@babel/preset-env", use "module:@babel/preset-env"
- Did you accidentally pass a preset as a plugin?
```

NextJS documentation says "*Next.js includes the `next/babel` preset to your app, which includes everything needed to compile React applications and server-side code.* ".

It would be great if someone can explain where/what is the right approach to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:

```js
// .babelrc file, also could be babel.config.js
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "preset-env": {},
        "transform-runtime": {},
        "styled-jsx": {},
        "class-properties": {}
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": []
}
```

Taken from: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config